# Switch muestre información del case 1 en el case 2 java

Tags: java, switch

Estoy realizando un proyecto para de la universidad, es un menú que tiene 3 opciones, una para ingresar los datos, otra para mostrar los datos ingresados y finalmente para que salga de la aplicación.

El profesor nos mostró una forma de realizarlo, entonces he estado siguiéndolo. Para la parte de ingresar los datos todo está funcionando bien, puedo devolverme al menú principal luego de ingresar lo que necesito todo, el problema es a la hora de mostrar los datos, ya que no me reconoce la información.

Según lo que nos recomendó fue usar un switch, entonces la parte de ingresar datos sería el case 1, la intención es que en el case 2 me traiga la información del case 1.

De verdad agradecería si alguien me ayuda a encontrar la forma de lograrlo, aunque es un proyecto básico ya me perdí en esa parte.

Este sería el código:

```html
public class Proyecto {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) { //Inicio del codigo
        int opcion = 0;//Menu principal
        do {
            opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una opcion: \n"
                    + "1. Ingresar datos\n"
                    + "2. Mostrar datos\n"
                    + "3. Salir"));
            switch (opcion) { //Switch del menu principal
                case 1://Menu ingreso de datos
                    int opcion1 = 0;
                    do {
                        opcion1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una opcion: \n"
                                + "1. Casos nuevos\n"
                                + "2. Personas hospitalizadas\n"
                                + "3. Personas en cuidados intensivos\n"
                                + "4. Personas fallecidas\n"
                                + "5. Personas recuperadas el dia de hoy\n"
                                + "6. Medidas preventivas\n"
                                + "0. Volver al menu principal"));
                        switch (opcion1) { //Switch del submenu de ingreso de datos
                            case 1:
                                int nuevos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de casos nuevos"));
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                int hospitalizados = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas hospitalizadas"));
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                int intensivos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas en cuidados intensivo"));
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                int fallecidos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas fallecidas"));
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                int recuperados = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas recuperadas el dia de hoy"));
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                String medida = "";
                                medida = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la medida preventiva");
                                break;
                            case 0:
                                break;
                            default:
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                break;
                        }//Fin del switch de ingreso de datos
                    } while (opcion1 != 0);
                    break;
                case 2://Menu de muestra de datos
                    int opcion2 = 0;
                    do {
                        opcion2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una opcion: \n"
                                + "1. Casos nuevos\n"
                                + "2. Personas hospitalizadas\n"
                                + "3. Personas en cuidados intensivos\n"
                                + "4. Personas fallecidas\n"
                                + "5. Personas recuperadas el dia de hoy\n"
                                + "6. Medidas preventivas\n"
                                + "7. Total de personas infectadas\n"
                                + "0. Volver al menu principal"));
                        switch (opcion2) {//Switch menu de muestra
                            case 1:
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de casos nuevos es" + nuevos);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas hospitalizadas es" + hospitalizados);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas personas en cuidados intensivos es" + intesivos);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas fallecidas es" + fallecidos);
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas recuperadas el dia de hoy es" + recuperados);
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las medidas preventivas son" + medidas);
                                break;
                            case 7:
                                int total = 0;
                                total = nuevos + hospitalizados + intensivos + fallecidos + recuperados;
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El total de infectados es" + total);
                                break;
                            case 0:
                                break;
                            default:
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                break;
                        }//Fin del switch del menu de muestra
                    } while (opcion2 != 0);
                    break;
                case 3: //Opcion Salir
                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }//Fin del switch del menu principal
        } while (opcion != 0);
    }//Fin del main
}//Fin del proyecto
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que declarar las variables donde almacenas los datos fuera del switch y así podrás acceder a sus valores desde el case 2, aquí te lo dejo corregido.

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) { //Inicio del codigo
    int opcion = 0;//Menu principal
    int nuevos = 0;
    int hospitalizados = 0;
    int intensivos = 0;
    int fallecidos = 0;
    int recuperados = 0;
    String medida = "";
    
    do {
        opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una opcion: \n"
                + "1. Ingresar datos\n"
                + "2. Mostrar datos\n"
                + "3. Salir"));
        switch (opcion) { //Switch del menu principal
            case 1://Menu ingreso de datos
                int opcion1 = 0;
                do {
                    opcion1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una opcion: \n"
                            + "1. Casos nuevos\n"
                            + "2. Personas hospitalizadas\n"
                            + "3. Personas en cuidados intensivos\n"
                            + "4. Personas fallecidas\n"
                            + "5. Personas recuperadas el dia de hoy\n"
                            + "6. Medidas preventivas\n"
                            + "0. Volver al menu principal"));
                    switch (opcion1) { //Switch del submenu de ingreso de datos
                        case 1:
                            nuevos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de casos nuevos"));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            hospitalizados = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas hospitalizadas"));
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            intensivos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas en cuidados intensivo"));
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            fallecidos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas fallecidas"));
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            recuperados = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas recuperadas el dia de hoy"));
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            medida = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la medida preventiva");
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            break;
                        default:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            break;
                    }//Fin del switch de ingreso de datos
                } while (opcion1 != 0);
                break;
            case 2://Menu de muestra de datos
                int opcion2 = 0;
                do {
                    opcion2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una opcion: \n"
                            + "1. Casos nuevos\n"
                            + "2. Personas hospitalizadas\n"
                            + "3. Personas en cuidados intensivos\n"
                            + "4. Personas fallecidas\n"
                            + "5. Personas recuperadas el dia de hoy\n"
                            + "6. Medidas preventivas\n"
                            + "7. Total de personas infectadas\n"
                            + "0. Volver al menu principal"));
                    switch (opcion2) {//Switch menu de muestra
                        case 1:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de casos nuevos es " + nuevos);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas hospitalizadas es " + hospitalizados);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas personas en cuidados intensivos es " + intensivos);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas fallecidas es " + fallecidos);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas recuperadas el dia de hoy es " + recuperados);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las medidas preventivas son " + medida);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            int total = 0;
                            total = nuevos + hospitalizados + intensivos + fallecidos + recuperados;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El total de infectados es " + total);
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            break;
                        default:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            break;
                    }//Fin del switch del menu de muestra
                } while (opcion2 != 0);
                break;
            case 3: //Opcion Salir
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }//Fin del switch del menu principal
    } while (opcion != 0);
}//Fin del main
```

}//Fin del proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está en el ámbito (scope) de las variables. Si las declaras dentro del *switch* sólo existirán ahí, en ese bloque y al salir de este, en el siguiente ciclo del bucle *do* dejarán de existir y se crearán unas nuevas. Prueba a ponerlas fuera del bucle para que sean accesibles desde cualquier parte de la función y usa dentro del switch las variables pero sin declarar (sin poner int o String delante)

```
public class Proyecto {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) { //Inicio del codigo
/****************** AÑADIR ESTO ******************/
    int nuevos;
    int hospitalizados;
    int intensivos;
    int fallecidos;
    int recuperados;
    String medida = "";
/****************** HASTA AQUI ******************/
    int opcion = 0;//Menu principal
    do {
        opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una opcion: \n"
                + "1. Ingresar datos\n"
                + "2. Mostrar datos\n"
                + "3. Salir"));
        switch (opcion) { //Switch del menu principal
            case 1://Menu ingreso de datos
                int opcion1 = 0;
                do {
                    opcion1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una opcion: \n"
                            + "1. Casos nuevos\n"
                            + "2. Personas hospitalizadas\n"
                            + "3. Personas en cuidados intensivos\n"
                            + "4. Personas fallecidas\n"
                            + "5. Personas recuperadas el dia de hoy\n"
                            + "6. Medidas preventivas\n"
                            + "0. Volver al menu principal"));
                    switch (opcion1) { //Switch del submenu de ingreso de datos
                        case 1:
/****************** QUITAR EL int ******************/
                            nuevos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de casos nuevos"));
                            break;
                        case 2:
/****************** QUITAR EL int ******************/
                            hospitalizados = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas hospitalizadas"));
                            break;
                        case 3:
/****************** QUITAR EL int ******************/
                            intensivos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas en cuidados intensivo"));
                            break;
                        case 4:
/****************** QUITAR EL int ******************/
                            fallecidos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas fallecidas"));
                            break;
                        case 5:
/****************** QUITAR EL int ******************/
                            recuperados = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de personas recuperadas el dia de hoy"));
                            break;
                        case 6:
/****************** QUITAR LA DECLARACION DEL STRING ******************/
                            medida = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la medida preventiva");
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            break;
                        default:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            break;
                    }//Fin del switch de ingreso de datos
                } while (opcion1 != 0);
                break;
            case 2://Menu de muestra de datos
                int opcion2 = 0;
                do {
                    opcion2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una opcion: \n"
                            + "1. Casos nuevos\n"
                            + "2. Personas hospitalizadas\n"
                            + "3. Personas en cuidados intensivos\n"
                            + "4. Personas fallecidas\n"
                            + "5. Personas recuperadas el dia de hoy\n"
                            + "6. Medidas preventivas\n"
                            + "7. Total de personas infectadas\n"
                            + "0. Volver al menu principal"));
                    switch (opcion2) {//Switch menu de muestra
                        case 1:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de casos nuevos es" + nuevos);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas hospitalizadas es" + hospitalizados);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas personas en cuidados intensivos es" + intesivos);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas fallecidas es" + fallecidos);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de personas recuperadas el dia de hoy es" + recuperados);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las medidas preventivas son" + medidas);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            int total = 0;
                            total = nuevos + hospitalizados + intensivos + fallecidos + recuperados;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El total de infectados es" + total);
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            break;
                        default:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            break;
                    }//Fin del switch del menu de muestra
                } while (opcion2 != 0);
                break;
            case 3: //Opcion Salir
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }//Fin del switch del menu principal
    } while (opcion != 0);
}//Fin del main
```

}//Fin del proyecto